# How do I make the data per row, because the data is in one row to input everything so I want one row of data

Tags: count, laravel-8

view

```
<td class="align-middle" style="text-align: center;">
                                       
                                        @forelse ($teknisi as $person)
                                    
                                        <?php
                                            $countteknisi = App\Models\ServiceOffline::where('teknisi_repair',$person->id)->whereIn('status_order',['0','1','3'])->count()
                                        ?>
                                        <option value="{{ $person->id }}">{{$countteknisi}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </td>
```

Controller

```
    public function index()
    {
        $teknisi = Teknisi::where('id_mitra', Auth::user()->id_mitra)->latest()->when(request()->q, function($teknisi) {
            $teknisi = $teknisi->where('name', 'like', '%'. request()->q . '%');
        })->whereNull('deleted_at')->paginate(10);
        $rating = TeknisiRating::all();
        $saldo = DB::table('saldo_mitra')->select(DB::raw('id_teknisi, SUM(saldo) as saldo'))->groupBy('id_teknisi')->get();
        $saldodone = DB::table('saldo_mitra')->select(DB::raw('id_teknisi, SUM(saldo) as saldo'))->where('status', 0)->groupBy('id_teknisi')->get();
        $saldopending = DB::table('saldo_mitra')->select(DB::raw('id_teknisi, SUM(saldo) as saldo'))->where('status', 1)->groupBy('id_teknisi')->get();
        return view('admin.teknisi.index',compact('teknisi', 'rating', 'saldo', 'saldodone', 'saldopending'));
    }
```

[image: display example]